# Spring websocket - Activemq listener integration

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I am using spring 4.0.0.rc1 websocket endpoint and topic.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.springframework.samples")
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocketendpoint").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
    }

}
```

But JMS listener can not post a message on websocket-topic. In this case I am using camel-consume annotation to listen to queue and post message to topic.

```
@Service
public class WebsocketTopicService implements ApplicationListener<BrokerAvailabilityEvent> 
{

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MessageChannelService.class);

    private final MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate;

    private AtomicBoolean brokerAvailable = new AtomicBoolean();


    @Autowired
    public MessageChannelService(MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate) {
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(BrokerAvailabilityEvent event) {
        this.brokerAvailable.set(event.isBrokerAvailable());
    }

    //@Scheduled(fixedDelay=2000)
    @Consume(uri="activemq:queue.out")
    public void processMessage(String msg){
        if (this.brokerAvailable.get()) {
            this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/message.status", msg);
            log.info("Sending quote " + msg);
        }
    }
```

Any idea why ??

Comment: You are using the simpleBroker and nothing related to a remote broker.  Change your configuration to use the actual implementation.

Comment: How to configure remote broker ??

Comment: See the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/MessageBrokerConfigurer.html) for the `MessageBrokerConfigurer ` and [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/StompBrokerRelayRegistration.html) for `StompBrokerRelayRegistration`.